# I cannot set default value in select list

Tags: angularjs

What am I doing wrong? Because I can't set default option on my select list with id = 995?

```
<script>
    var model = {"MeetingPlacesList":[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Place 991","Value":"991"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Place 993","Value":"993"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Place 995","Value":"995"}]};


var myApplication = angular.module('MyApplication', []);

    myApplication.controller('MeetingController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {        
        $scope.MeetingPlacesList = model.MeetingPlacesList;

        $scope.FormData = {};
        $scope.FormData.SelectedMeetingPlaceId = 995; // it doeasn't work
    });
</script>

<select name="SelectedMeetingPlaceId" ng-model="FormData.SelectedMeetingPlaceId" ng-options="place.Value as place.Text for place in MeetingPlacesList"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a string :

```
$scope.FormData.SelectedMeetingPlaceId = "995";
```

Because the comparison is made with strict equality.

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ydnj6my4/)**

Answer (score 0):

It need to be a string. In angularjs the comparison is always strict. So 995 is not same as '995'. That's why you're not seeing the value set.

```
$scope.FormData.SelectedMeetingPlaceId = '995';
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yovige/1/edit?html,js,output)**